# Firebase cloud functions pricing for outbound data transfer to a GAE app

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing a chat-like Firebase project with a cloud function that sends every chat message to a GAE app to index the text so that I can do text queries with the Search API.

The Firebase function pricing page (https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing) says that "outbound data to other Google APIs in the same region is free".

- First question: Does this apply to my case? I mean, my GAE app would have the same consideration as any other Google API?
- Second question: In such case, how do I know both services are in the same region?

Answer (score 1):

Your own GAE instance is not considered a "Google API".  Google APIs are services like Gmail, Cloud Translate, and reCAPTCHA, which are fully controlled by Google.